# 3e5 in java for android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I work in javascript but I'm participating in a project for android.
I'm trying to write great numbers. In JS I'd write, for example 3e5 to get 300000.
Is it the same in Java, I searched but I couldn't get an answer not using pow ^

Comment: I don't understand why you don't can in Android with Math.pow, see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html. For larger numbers above you can use BigInteger class.

Comment: Do you need integer or floating-point numbers?

Comment: Are you trying to write these values as literals in source code, or parsing user input?

Comment: @Gil float numbers, JonSkeet, writing on the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In JS I'd write, for example 3e5 to get 300000

In java is almost (*) the same:

```
double x = 3e5;
float y = 3e5f;
```

This is for floating-point numbers, here is the complete spec for floating-point literals: [JSL-3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

For integers this is not supported in java. You can force a narrowing primitive conversion, but keep in mind you might lose precision:

```
int n = (int) 3e5;
```

(*) Footnote: I don't know JS, but it looks the same to me in this example.